Why does it matter so much in Linux to add or remove whitespace in commands?
In the following command to change the Bash prompt of a user in bash terminal
PS1='[\d]\u@\h:\w$'

This command throws an error "command not found" if --> I leave a whitespace before the "=" or after the "=".
I was expecting all  of the following:
↣ PS1 = '[\d]\u@\h:\w$'
↣ PS1 ='[\d]\u@\h:\w$'
↣ PS1= '[\d]\u@\h:\w$'
↣ PS1='[\d]\u@\h:\w$'

to produce the same result but only the 4th one works fine and top3 throws error - "command not found".

With a space after the PS1, that's not an assignment, it's running a command named PS1. With a space after =, that's running the command '[\d]\u@\h:\w$' (not a meaningful command, but the shell isn't responsible for knowing that!) with an environment variable PS1 having an empty value temporarily defined. With spaces both before and after the =, you're running a command PS1 with its first argument being = and its second argument being [\d]\u@\h:\w$.

So the lack of whitespace matters in this context because all the other ways to do it have their own specific meanings, such that a shell needs to interpret them a particular way to avoid violating the POSIX.2 standard (which is itself from the early 90s, but is informed by behavior of shells from the 70s and 80s).

That said, note that "why" questions are very likely to be closed as off-topic, as Stack Overflow's rules (and more generally the rules of most Stack Exchange sites) require questions to be about solving a specific practical problem (and if you know the right thing, even if you don't like that right thing, you don't really have a problem); see What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design? on [meta.se].

@VanashajB10 — I want to explicitly point out ... you ask "Why does it matter so much in Linux", and the reality is that it doesn't matter in Linux, it matters to the shell (often bash) that you are running on Linux.

Shell syntax mostly thinks of the command line as a series of "words". PS1='[\d]\u@\h:\w$' is one word, while PS1 = '[\d]\u@\h:\w$' is three separate words, so to the shell they're completely different things.

Basic syntax for a bash command: VAR1=VAL1 VAR2=VAL2 CMD PAR1 PAR2 executes command CMD with arguments PAR1 and PAR2 in an environment with variable VAR1 is set to value VAL1, and similar to the subsequent variable(s). The variable assignement and the command part are optional. If you write FOO  =  BAR,  you run the command FOO with parameters = and BAR. If you write FOO= BAR, you run the command BAR in an environment where FOO is set to the empty string.
